# Conditionally delay function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, frontend

In front-end JavaScript, I have a function `funcA` which normally executes *as soon as* the client receives a particular message `A`.

It is possible that the server will send another message `B` *before* sending `A`. When this happens, the client will receive two messages: first `B` then `A`, and a different function `funcB` (triggered by `B`) will execute before `funcA`.

Now, **is there an elegant way** to delay the execution of `funcA` upon receiving `A`, if `funcB` executes first?

Some pseudo-code below to illustrate the idea:

```
...

// called upon receiving msg `A`
// but need to delay its execution if receiving `B` and executing funcB first
function funcA(param) {
    ...
}

// called upon receiving msg `B`
function funcB(param) {
    ...
}

...

// receiving messages from server

var msg = JSON.parse(...);

if (msg.type === 'A') {
    funcA(msg.data);
}
else if (msg.type === 'B') {
    funcB(msg.data);
}
else if (msg.type === 'C') {
    ...
}

// deal with other types of message
...
```

I can think of using the combination of a 'flag' and conditional check before *every* execution of `funcA`, which doesn't seem very elegant to me.

Please note: this question is *not* about how to delay the execution of a function (which is usually achieved by using `setTimeout`), instead, it asks for a design pattern/structure given a particular code logic.

Comment: What code do you have now? Can you show it?

Comment: Programming and elegance aren't always the best of friends.  Using a flag in this instance is perfectly acceptable.  I'd do it without consideration in this scenario.

Comment: way in case you have message B  not to put meassage A as part of B call only funcB with funcA callback

Comment: @AlexKneller, could you elaborate the idea more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to keep track if `funcB` has been called, then you can check for that inside `funcA` and let it call itself with a delay:

```
var funcBCalled = false;

function funcB() {
  funcBCalled = true;
  // do something...
}

function funcA() {
  if (funcBCalled) {
    funcBCalled = false;
    window.setTimeout(funcA, 1000);
  } else {
    // do something
  }
}
```